# why I am getting never type in useReducer in TS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-reducer

I am making a reducer state of three values, `conversations`- intially empty array with the described properties, `messages` - intially empty array with described properties and `activeConversation` string. But I keep on getting typescript never errors. I don't understand. Can someone please resolve this for me ?

```
import { useReducer, useContext, createContext, FunctionComponent } from 'react';

export interface IConversations {
  conversationId: string;
  latestMessage: {
    latestMessageText: string;
    createdAt: string;
  };
  recipientUser: {
    fullName: string;
    email: string;
    online: boolean;
    recipientUserId: string;
    profileImg?: string;
  };
}

export interface IMessages {
  _id: string;
  author: string;
  text: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
}

interface IMessageReducer {
  conversations: IConversations[];
  messages: IMessages[];
  activeConversation: string;
}

type Action =
  | { type: 'UPLOAD_PROFILE'; profileImg: string }

type Dispatch = (action: Action) => void;

interface IUseMessage {
  messageState: IMessageReducer;
  dispatchMessageContext: Dispatch;
}

const messageReducer = (state: IMessageReducer, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const MessageContext = createContext({
  conversations: [],
  messages: [],
  activeConversations: ''
});

const MessageProvider: FunctionComponent = ({ children }): JSX.Element => {
  const [messageState, dispatchMessageContext] = useReducer(messageReducer, {
    conversations: [],
    messages: [],
    activeConversations: ''
  });

  return <MessageContext.Provider value={{ messageState, dispatchMessageContext }}>{children}</MessageContext.Provider>
}

const useMessage = (): IMessageReducer => {
  const context = useContext(MessageContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useMessage must be used within a MessageProvider');
  }
  return context;
}

export { MessageProvider, useMessage }
```

Comment: I think you need generics here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use typescript generics here and "force" the react context to understand the types it is using.

So instead of

```
const MessageContext = createContext({
```

it should be

```
const MessageContext = createContext<IMessageReducer>({
```

and

```
const [messageState, dispatchMessageContext] = useReducer(messageReducer, {
```

should become

```
const [messageState, dispatchMessageContext] = useReducer<
Reducer<IMessageReducer, any>(messageReducer, {
```

Comment: what errors? can you post a codesandbox or sth similar? the `never` error is because you have not declared the types used, that's why you use generics for this purpose.

Comment: Here is the sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-grothendieck-o3zvm?file=/src/useMessageContext.tsx). Ignore the `JSX` error, but all the other three is I am getting.

Comment: sorry i didnt remember the exact typing. updated my answer. it should be `<
Reducer<IMessageReducer, any>`

Comment: also you had a typo --> `activeConversations` --> `activeConversation`

Comment: i have altered the sandbox a little bit. https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-wood-475gz

Comment: Thank you @Apostolos